# Запоминание Tabs Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, javascript, bootstrap

Добрый вечер!

Столкнулся с проблемой сохранения нужной вкладки при обновлении страницы. Может, кто-то сталкивался и знает, как решить данную проблему?

Мой код: http://jsfiddle.net/wxnaf15v/1/
Таб запоминается, а информация-то нет, в чём, собственно говоря, проблема?

Comment: кто знает, как решить проблему?

Comment: посмотрите [это видео][1], возможно, это поможет решить вашу проблему

[1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAjAUmtGylY

Comment: а вообще [вот пример][1] передачи параметра для открытия нужной вкладки, а если ссылка на вкладку уходит в hash, то вообще просто, если не уходит, то сохраняйте в localstorage

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/wxnaf15v/2/

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду,
не могли бы Вы подсказать, как переделать мой вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/wxnaf15v/4/), кардинально переработал ваш код, вы зачем-то пытаетесь продублировать функционал табов, который уже реализован в twitter bootstrap.

```
var storage = localStorage.getItem('item');

if (storage && storage !== "#") {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + storage + '"]').tab('show');
}

var list = $('ul.nav').find('li');

$('ul.nav').on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function() {
    var itemId = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    localStorage.setItem('item', itemId);
});
```

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ Вам спасибо.
Очень выручили

Comment: ещё хотел добавить, что эта строчка `var list = $('ul.nav').find('li');` в данном варианте не нужна, забыл убрать